# Is it possible to restrict a method to a specific namespace?

Tags: c#, generics, namespaces, constraints, restriction

I've got a class named NetworkDevice within the namespace Classes.Device and a method:

```
private void DisplayDeviceDetails<T>(T device)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If I got that right, I may restrict the Type of T like so:

```
private void DisplayDeviceDetails<T>(T device) where T : Classes.Device.NetworkDevice
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Because I may add other devices in the future I'm wondering if there is a way to expand this behaviour to the namespace Classes.Devices like "where T : Classes.Devices"?
Or is creating a Baseclass "Device" the way to go?

I couldn't find anything else besides removing the constraint and checking inside the method itself via

```
object.OriginElement.GetType().Namespace
```

Other information was 5+ years old.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why do you want this restriction? Does it matter if someone uses this with a type outside of that namespace? If the types in that namespace have something in common for which `DisplayDeviceDetails`, you could make them inherit from a base class or implement an interface.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Actually no, I think I'll be the only one using it. I guess the main reason is because I like learning more about the language, comprehend fully why this is implemented and what all my options are to make at least better decisions while writing code - since I think there is no "right" way with stuff like that. Just good and bad practice ?!

Comment: _"Or is creating a Baseclass `Device` the way to go?"_ - yes, it is. _"Other information was 5+ years old."_ - quite a lot has changed in the C# world in last 5-10 years, but core concepts remained more or less the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a base class DeviceBase within the `Classes.Devices` namespace:

```
namespace Classes.Devices
{
    public abstract class DeviceBase
    {
        // Codes...
    }
}
```

Then, modify your method to accept only types derived from `DeviceBase`:

```
private void DisplayDeviceDetails<T>(T device) where T : Classes.Devices.DeviceBase
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

This way, any class within the Classes.Devices namespace that inherits from DeviceBase can be passed to the DisplayDeviceDetails method.

- **Alternatively, you can use interfaces if you prefer a more flexible approach.**

Comment: This does **not** constrain the type to being in a specific namespace.  Derived types can be in any namespace.  They specifically mention in the question that they can constraint the type to a specific type, and that isn't what they want to do.

Comment: Change the access modifier of the class to internal.

Comment: That restricts the assembly, not the namespace.